# Why zeta(2) in these inifinite sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, experimental-mathematics

The infinite sum of the reciprocals of these two sequences have zeta(2) in the result. The value is not in OEIS.
[A000326](https://oeis.org/A000326) [A002411](https://oeis.org/A002411) **Edit---rolled back the changes. Both $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$ are important.** 
$$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sum _{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2}n (3 n-1)}=
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}n^2 (n+1)}=
2\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-1\right)$$

Is there anything significant about this that might relate to zeta(2)? Or RH?

Comment: Is there a reason the $\frac12$ factor to be there? It cancels the $2$ in the right-hand side, so unless there is a reason that it's there I would remove it.

Comment: The second is easy: $$\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} - \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2}n(3n-1)=\frac{1}{2}m^2(m+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have left out the $\frac{1}{2}$ and the $2$. I would have found [A011379](https://oeis.org/A011379) and this comment:

> $\sum_{n>0} 1/a(n) = (\pi^2 - 6)/6 = 0.6449340..$ [Jolley eq 272] - Gary W. Adamson, Dec 22 2006

Thank-you for your efforts.

Comment: @Vibhav Pant: Usually, I keep the clips from OEIS in the original format to make it easier to find among the comments. However, this has multiple review approvals, so we will keep it. Thanks for the edit.